# Import python files from other directory without sys.path.append or changing PATH

Tags: python, import, module, path, sys.path

I have the following folder structure

```
project
  +folder src
    +file main.py
    +file __init__.py
  +folder tests
    +file test.py
    +file __init__.py
  +file __init__.py
```

All `__init__` files are empty.

Now I want to be able to run `test.py` form **anywhere**, this is important.

`test.py` calls

```
import src
```

because it needs functions from `main.py`.
This leads to an error:

```
ImportError: no module named src
```

Solutions I found include adding a `sys.path.append` command to `test.py` or adding the folder src to my `PATH` environment variable - is there no other way?

I cannot force every user to change their `PATH` and I cannot add `sys.path.append` commands to all test files.

Comment: Can you remove the requirement to run anywhere?  You could require that test.py is stored in your project directory and prompt for the target directory at run time.  You would import src first then call os.chdir('/run/script/here/')

Answer (score 1):

You can create a package of your application and install it in the environment you are running the tests from. See here for a tutorial http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/